# Focal chord property of Rectangular Hyperbola proof using eucildean Geometry .

Tags: geometry

In a rectangular hyperbola prove without using coordinate geometry that focal chord extension to the asymptotes are in equal , that is lets says a focal chord PQ intersect the asymptotes at A, B respectively then PA=QB . Is there a concept of stretching and squishing to make a symmetric chord out of the unsymmetric one and then show its equal ?

Comment: That is true even for a non-focal chord.

Comment: Can you give a geometric proof @Intelligentipauca

Comment: Didn't think these type of question would be difficult to some named problem destroyer

Comment: @Buraian we all are humans we have limit to how much we can do and not , i hope you understand

Comment: I have solved by coordinate geometry through @Buraian so its not like i didnt destroyed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prove a lemma, first of all. If from a point $P$ on a hyperbola we drop to the transverse axis $CL$ a perpendicular $PN$, meeting the asymptotes at $S$ and $T$ (see figure below), then:
$$
SN^2:CN^2=OL^2:CL^2=CM^2:CL^2.
$$
On the other hand, from $CN^2/CL^2-PN^2/CM^2=1$ one gets:
$$
PN^2:(CN^2-CL^2)=CM^2:CL^2.
$$
Combining these proportions we obtain:
$$
(SN^2-PN^2):CL^2=CM^2:CL^2
\ \implies\ 
SN^2-PN^2=CM^2,
$$
that is:
$$
(SN+PN)\cdot(SN-PN)=CM^2
$$
and finally:
$$
\tag{1}
PT\cdot PS=CM^2.
$$

Let's prove now the requested result.
Given then a chord $PQ$ (not necessarily a focal chord), produced to intersect the asymptotes at $A$ and $B$, let's drop from $P$ a perpendicular $PN$ to the transverse axis as described above, and from $Q$ another perpendicular to $CL$, meeting the asymptotes at $U$ and $V$. By similar triangles we then have:
$$
PA:PS = QA:QU
\quad\text{and}\quad
PB:PT=QB:QV,
$$
which combined give:
$$
(PA\cdot PB):(PS\cdot PT)=(QA\cdot QB):(QU\cdot QV).
$$
But by lemma $(1)$ above we have: $PS\cdot PT=QU\cdot QV=CM^2$,
hence:
$$
\begin{align}
PA\cdot PB &= QA\cdot QB\\
PA\cdot (PQ+QB) &= (QP+PA)\cdot QB\\
PA\cdot PQ &= QP\cdot QB\\
PA &= QB\\
\end{align}
$$
as it was to be proven.

[image]

The proof requires some changes if $P$ and $Q$ lie on different branches of the hyperbola, and is left to the reader.

Comment: Nice method , is it possible to do so by squishing and stretching some axis ?